# geting data out of a html table and send it to a view in pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid, pylons

We use pyramid and chameleon template.

Currently we have a page where users can fill in a table.
This table has a variable lenght because rows are added dynamically.
We want to get all the content of the table and put it in a list, so we can send it to our database.

The biggest problem is that we don't know how to send the data to a list and get it to our vieuw.
can some1 help me with this problem?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about the actual HTML code for a table? Maybe this isn't a pyramid question but a javascript thing? I would take all the HTML, send it to a view and parse it there. Just do a POST request.

Comment: oke thanks, I'm new in the entire concept of html, js and pyramid so i'm having some troubles.
Do you maybe have anny example of how i am supposed to do this ?

Comment: Presumably you are going to be posting data back to your app, either in an HTML form or with JavaScript. Either way, the data will be available to your Pyramid controller as request.POST ... you're going to have to show more about what you have already if you want more useful feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I will post an example of how I would to it with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

Suppose this is your table:

```
<table id="my_table">
    <tr>
        <td>Some text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then you do this in JavaScript:

```
$.post(
    "{{request.route_url('table_data_view')}}", // chamelon output
    {'data': $("#my_table").html()}
);
```

I don't know about chameleon so the url generation might be wrong. On the pyramid side you now have something like:

```
@view_config(route_name='table_data_view')
def table_data(request):
    data = request.POST["data"]
    process_data(data)
    return HTTPFound(location=...)
```

Hope this helps.